# Powershell start takes long time

Tags: windows, powershell-2.0

this is a strange problem. I'm sure this worked fine some two months ago and now suddenly this. when I start powershell (directly from the start menu or from cmd. as admin or not) I get these lines:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6
```

then it is frozen for more than 30 seconds and after that, I get the command line and cursor and I can write

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6
PS C:\Users\user>
```

I searched a lot all over the internet but all the workarounds with some commands didn't help. In the end, all the discussions were either too old and this is probably something new.
Any idea what could go wrong? I didn't install anything just the windows updates (but more of them and not sure when it started to behave like this. I'm on windows 10 pro latest update

thanks a lot for any tips
Marek

Comment: I'd check your PS profile for corruption or for a command which it can't find. You could also try reinstalling PowerShell.

Comment: thanks a lot. I tried to remove windows feature powershell 2.0, however it doesn't remove the powershell totally. it didn't help. is there some way to remove or cleanup the ps "profile" ? where is it ?

Comment: Try starting powershell without your profile: powershell.exe -noprofile

Comment: thank you. unfortunately either with -noprofile it is still 29 seconds to give me the command line. really strange :(

Answer (score 1):

After analize powershell.exe with procmon (sysinternals tool) I could see that the process was trying to do something in catroot2 folder, so after rename it (you have to stop the CryptSvc service that blocks the folder), it was created automatically. So the conclusion is that folder got corrupted. (Sorry for my bad English)

Execute the next .bat

```bash
net stop CryptSvc /y
rename c:\windows\system32\catroot2 Catroot2.bak
net start CryptSvc
```

Comment: That sounds like an incredibly specific fix that may have worked for you. Can you expand on this answer to give some more details about how it works, etc.?